# Tagging docker images and adding variables in docker-compose

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker to build and deploy applications. After building the image i need to tag and use that image from another system which has docker-compose on it. I'm using Jenkins to build and deploy images to private docker registries.  Docker compose file on the host system should automatically pull those images based on tag version.

How to pass variables to docker-compose to substitute tag values ?

Example:
if a=2.4 then it should substitute 2.4 inside docker-compose file for a.

```
version: '2'
services:
 web:
  image: httpd:$a
  ports:
    - 80:80
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use this as written.  Docker compose will use your OS environment to populate variables using the syntax that you have here.

On Mac/Linux:

```
export a=2.4
docker-compose up
```

Comment: Thanks and when i export variables from jenkins machine to client machine , i couldn't read the variable from the shell inside client machine. I'm getting following error:
WARNING: The a variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string

Comment: I have added in a .bashrc and everything works as expected. Thanks